# Find and gzip files in subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have *.xls files in the location /home/Docs/Calc. There are multiple subdirectories inside that folder. Eg

```
/home/Docs/Calc/2011
/home/Docs/Calc/2012
/home/Docs/Calc/2013
```

I can gzip each file under the subdirectories using the find command,

```
find /home/Docs/Calc -iname "*.xls" -exec gzip {} \;
```

but how can I gzip all the files in each subdirectory ? eg.

```
/home/Docs/Calc/2011/2011.tar.gz
/home/Docs/Calc/2012/2012.tar.gz
/home/Docs/Calc/2013/2013.tar.gz
```

I must add that /home/Docs/Calc is one of the many folders eg Calc-work, calc-tax, calc-bills. All of these have the year subfolders in them

Answer (score 5):

Since we don't have to recurse, I'd approach it not with `find` but with globbing and a `for` loop. If we're in the `Calc` directory, `echo *` will give us all the directory names:

```
~/Docs/Calc$ echo *
2011 2012 2013
```

It just so happens that we can use a `for` loop to iterate over these and tar them up in the usual way:

```
for year in *; do
    tar czf $year.tar.gz $year
done
```

If you want the resulting tarballs in the year directories, you could add an `mv` after the `tar` command. I'd be hesitant to put the tarball in the directory from outset or tar might start trying to tar its own output into itself.

Comment: Thanks @icktoofay. Apologies for not mentioning that I am looking for searching across multiple folders. I have multiple folders under Doc, one of them is calc. eg. ~/Docs/Calc,~/Docs/Calc-work/.. and so on. These have .xls files sorted in year format. This is why I was trying to use the find command

Comment: @icktoofay I don't understand why so many votes, because this doesn't work at all...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Please elaborate.  This does what it says it does (modulo the bug that directory names with whitespace or wildcards in them will not work; [proper quoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) would fix that).

Comment: It would be more robust to restrict to just directories, with `for year in */` (notice the slash).

Answer (score 3):

I set up a simple function in my .bashrc:

```
function gzdp () {
find . -type f -name "$@" -exec gzip {} \;
}
```

The `$@` automatically gets replaced with whatever comes after `gzdp` when you call the function. Now, in your command window you can navigate to the `/home/Docs/Calc/` folder and just call:

```
gzdp *.txt
```

and it should zip all .txt files in all lower subdirectories.

Not sure if this helps or not, my first post on this website. Careful that you don't accidentally `gzip` unwanted .txt files.

Comment: No; if the wildcard matches a single file in the current directory, it will find only files with precisely that name.  If multiple files match, it will cause a syntax error from the `find` command.  `gzdp '*.txt'` should do what you say, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find /home/Docs/Calc -type d -exec tar cvzf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/Docs/Calc/ -mindepth 1 -type d | while read -r DIR; do
    NAME=${DIR##*/}
    pushd "$DIR" >/dev/null && {
        tar -cvpzf "${NAME}.tar.gz" *
        popd >/dev/null
    }
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/Docs/Calc/
find=`find . -type d`
for f in $find; do
    cd $f   
    tar -cvz *.xls >> ${f##*/}.tar.gz
    cd -
done
```